# Sample widget code which get data(1-5 record) from Wp_Admin panel and display to Homepage(Wordpress Custom Theme)

Tags: widgets

Anybody here who help me how to fetch data and display to Homepage 
for example 
i enter 4-5 student record to database using WP-Admin Panel
that record automatically display to Homepage using any loop.

Student Info 
   1- Name 
   2- Class
   3- Result
   ... etc
when i enter these data in WP-admin panel that will automatically display to Homepage (index.php)
i want sample(slimier) code for any other example 

I want code for

  1-Functions.php

  2- index.php

[image]

Comment: Hi! There are many ways to go about this and it will depend on your end goal. You can setup a Widget, have a Custom Post Type or event create your own table. Would you care to elaborate on the project?

Comment: Asking for help is not a question. Please edit your question and be specific about what API or concept are you having trouble with.

Comment: @pedroCoitinho can you give me sample code which match with my problem

Comment: @M.Nadeem I would be happy to help, but we need more information as to what you need to do, as Mark Kaplun pointed out

Answer (score 0):

As everyone commented above, you need to explain where you are having problem,

there are a lot of ways to achieve what you want to do,

**Option 1 :**

**Advance Custom Field Plugin:**

https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/

this can help you to create custom fields at the admin panel and display them at front-end,

please see the plugin manual for further instructions on how it works,

**Option 2 :**

**Define custom Widget Area:** check out WordPress manual here is the link:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Widgetizing_Themes

Thanks,